# No matching distribution found

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, pip, package

I am trying to collect all the wheel files for libffi-dev. Trying the command mentioned below:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=setup libffi-dev
```

is giving

Collecting libffi-dev

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libffi-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libffi-dev
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

`libffi-dev` is the name of the Ubuntu package. `cffi` is the one from PyPI. You need to install both:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
pip install cffi
```

Comment: looks like my /etc/apt/sources.list was not pointing to the internet :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install wordcloud and facing this issue.

From https://pypi.org/simple/wordcloud/   download the corresponding .whl file for the Python version and OS you are using. (I have downloaded wordcloud-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl  meant for 64 bit windows).

Place the file in `C:\Users\<User>`

From command prompt run

```
pip install --verbose --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org wordcloud-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

This worked for me. Found this solution after a lot of research.

```
C:\Users\**<user>**>pip install --verbose --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org wordcloud-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-hqkva4rs
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-0cimhb2c
Created requirements tracker 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-0cimhb2c'
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y5b3ck8i
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Processing c:\users\<user>\wordcloud-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
  Added wordcloud==1.5.0 from file:///C:/Users/<user>/wordcloud-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-0cimhb2c'
  Removed wordcloud==1.5.0 from file:///C:/Users/<user>/wordcloud-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-0cimhb2c'
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud==1.5.0) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud==1.5.0) (1.15.1)
Installing collected packages: wordcloud

Successfully installed wordcloud-1.5.0
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-0cimhb2c'
```

Comment: Place the file in C:\Users\<user>   - Please note this correction Jomon